# One dimensional wave equation -numerical vs analitcal solution?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, wavelet-analysis

Recently I have been experimenting with one dimensional wave equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions. So the problem goes like this:
[image: jpg1]

I found this formulas in: Qiong-Gui Lin "Yet another approach to solutions of the one-dimensional wave equations with inhomogeneous boundary conditions", Am. J. Phys. 90 (1), 31 (2022).

[image: jpg2]
Now here's what I done using Mathematica:

```
$Assumptions = c > 0;
eq = {D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - (1/c^2)*D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0}
s1 = Simplify[DSolve[eq, u[x, t], {x, t}]]
wp = {u[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0};
c = 1;
L = 1;
u0 = 1;
alfa = 3;
mu1[t_] := u0*(alfa*t)^2*E^(-alfa*t)
mu[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {u0*(alfa*t)^2*E^(-alfa*t), t >= 0}}]
wb = {DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == mu1[t], x == 0], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, x == L]};
tmax = 6;
s = NDSolve[{eq, wp, wb}, u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

So basically now I solved wave equation numerically. Here is graph of solution.

```
    r1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. s[[1]]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u(x,t)"}]
```

[image: r1]
Now what i want to do is compare the numerical solution with the solution given by the formulas (1) and (2). So I defined piecewise function

```
uu[x_, t_] :=  Piecewise[{{mu[t - x/c], {t > 0 && t <= L/c}}, {mu[t - x/c] - 
mu[t - (2 L - x)/c], {t >= L/c && t <= 2 L/c}}, {mu[t - x/c] + 
mu[t - (2 L + x)/c] - 
mu[t - (2 L - x)/c], {t >= 2 L/c && t <= 3 L/c}}, {mu[t - x/c] + 
mu[t - (2 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c] - 
mu[t - (4 L - x)/c], {t >= 3 L/c && t <= 4 L/c}}, {mu[t - x/c] + 
mu[t - (4 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c] - 
mu[t - (4 L - x)/c], {t >= 4 L/c && t <= 5 L/c}}, {mu[t - x/c] + 
mu[t - (2 L + x)/c] + mu[t - (4 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c] -
mu[t - (4 L - x)/c] - 
mu[t - (2 L - x)/c], {t >= 5 L/c && t <= 6 L/c}}}]
```

I suspected that graph of this function will look similar to graph r1 (which I get by numerical solution). But actually it looks like this:

```
r2 = Plot3D[uu[x, t], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image: r2]

Which is nothing like graph r1. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? Why the numerical solution and analytical different so much?

Here is link to my notebook

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jz1Qp3fzOB809j0O4e_TX_g_h8j76ePX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `DSolve[{eq, wp, wb}, u[x, t], {x, t}]` returns the input. What discordance do you say about?

Comment: I know that the answer return by DSolve is correct but why graph of function uu which i defined differs so much from the graph r1?

Comment: All of your conditions are surrounded by curly brackets.  For example, `{t >= L/c && t <= 2 L/c}` should just be `t >= L/c && t <= 2 L/c`

Answer (score 4):

The piece-wise domain shown in the image doesn't seem to be correct. The second one in particular, though you typed in correctly in your code, should be

$$(2n+1)l/c<t\leq(2n+2)l/c\;.$$

I assume that was just a typo. Anyways, I had no motivation to look for an error in your function `uu` (no offense) and just used the following

```
uu[x_, t_, s_] := Piecewise[
   Join[
    Table[{
      Sum[mu[t - (2*k*L + x)/c], {k, 0, n}] - 
       Sum[mu[t - (2*k*L - x)/c], {k, 1, n}],
      2*n*L/c < t <= (2 n + 1)*L/c
      }, {n, 0, s}],
    Table[{
      Sum[mu[t - (2*k*L + x)/c], {k, 0, n}] - 
       Sum[mu[t - (2*k*L - x)/c], {k, 1, n + 1}],
      (2*n + 1)*L/c < t <= (2 n + 2)*L/c
      }, {n, 0, s}]
    ]
   ];
```

where `s` is the summation order. To plot with `s=5`,

```
Plot3D[uu[x, t, 5], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for Your answer! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer and an extended comment.

Your question is well-written and clearly explains the issue.  But I think the issue is just a wrong use of the `Piecewise` function.  Just removing the curly brackets around the constraints fixes that problem.  Therefore, your question is likely to be closed.

```
uu[x_, t_] := Piecewise[{{mu[t - x/c], t > 0 && t <= L/c}, 
  {mu[t - x/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c], t >= L/c && t <= 2 L/c}, 
  {mu[t - x/c] + mu[t - (2 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c], t >= 2 L/c && t <= 3 L/c}, 
  {mu[t - x/c] + mu[t - (2 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c] - mu[t - (4 L - x)/c], t >= 3 L/c && t <= 4 L/c}, 
  {mu[t - x/c] + mu[t - (4 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c] - mu[t - (4 L - x)/c], t >= 4 L/c && t <= 5 L/c},
  {mu[t - x/c] + mu[t - (2 L + x)/c] + mu[t - (4 L + x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c] - mu[t - (4 L - x)/c] - mu[t - (2 L - x)/c], t >= 5 L/c && t <= 6 L/c}}]

Plot3D[uu[x, t], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image: 3D plot]

Comment: (+1) Why didn't you upvote the question if its well written?

Comment: The question is well-written by a new contributor (everything necessary was clear and included) but the error is something that could be easily found in the documentation and therefore likely to be closed.  So I gave an answer to help but is unlikely to help anyone else (my opinion).  It's a good sign that the OP will likely write future questions with the same clarity.  But why upvote a question that will be closed?  (That's a question, not a statement.)

Comment: I understand and follow your reasoning. Seen that OP is new here and put considerable effort into formulating the question - much more in fact than looking the issue up in the documentation - makes me believe that OP could not find relevant parts in the documentation. Upvoting a well written question just makes people feel welcome; and if it's closed - so what?

Comment: @JimB Thank You for Your answer. I've tried write my question as clearly as possible. I have hard time doing that because i had a big problem with edditing my post. For some reason there was an error with my code. That's why i put two picuters and not LaTeX code.